# How to do wapiti security test step by step procedure in windows 7 (Its show no error)

Tags: python-2.7, wapiti

[image]Installed python 2.7

```
D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src> python wapiti.py <server url>/ -s
```

i didnt get any errors. i got one html file with no error

```
D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src> python wapiti.py http://serverdomain/Dashboard/Index/ -u



D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\net> python getcookie.py http://serverdomain/Dashboard/Index/ -c <file url>

D:\wapiti\wapiti-2.2.1\src> python wapiti.py http://serverdomain/Dashboard/Index/ -a username%password
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You download the zip (wapiti-2.3.0-win32-standalone) package,extract it and change directory into it (e.g. cd wapiti-2.0.X)

2.Install the Python 2.6 or 2.7 on window machine.

Execute the below command using cmd :-

```
#wapiti-getcookie  cookies.json  http://stage.xxxxxxx.com/login

#wapiti http://stage.xxxxxxxx.com -c cookies.json -x http://stage.xxxxxxx.com/logout
```